# Multiple issues after migrating the Flame package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I got the below class but having multiple errors when I update my package. I didn't manage to capture what was my previous version but it was working before but I'm using flame: ^1.6.0 now.

```
class Monkey extends PositionComponent with HasHitboxes, Collidable, HasGameRef<MovingBackgroundGame> {
  Monkey({Vector2? position, bool isVertical = false})
      : super(
          position: position,
          size: Vector2(40, 80),
          anchor: Anchor.topLeft,
        );

  bool collided = false;
  HitboxShape hitbox = HitboxRectangle(relation: Vector2(1, 1));

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    addHitbox(hitbox);
    super.onLoad();
  }
```

These are the following errors that I got. I tried to follow the documentation but haven't seen about these errors.
`HasHitboxes` and `Collidable` - Classes can only mix in mixins and classes.
`HitboxShape` - Undefined class 'HitboxShape'.
`HitboxRectangle` - The method 'HitboxRectangle' isn't defined for the type 'Monkey'.
`addHitbox` - The method 'addHitbox' isn't defined for the type 'Monkey'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HasHitboxes` and `Collidable` mixins are no longer needed, so you can just remove those ones. You can add `CollisionCallbacks` if you want to react to collisions within this component though.

Then the `HitboxRectangle` has been renamed to `RectangleHitbox` and since you set the relation to (1, 1) you don't actually have to add anything at all in its constructor since (1, 1) is the default.

`addHitbox` is removed since hitboxes now are normal components.

This is what the class would look like in `v1.6.0`:

```dart
class Monkey extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks, HasGameRef<MovingBackgroundGame> {
  Monkey({Vector2? position, bool isVertical = false})
      : super(
          position: position,
          size: Vector2(40, 80),
          anchor: Anchor.topLeft,
        );

  RectangleHitbox hitbox = RectangleHitbox();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    addHitbox(hitbox);
  }
}
```

I would guess that you were on maybe `v1.0.0` before you upgraded.

Comment: Hi spydon, I really appreciate your help in explaining this. I had a hard time understanding what I'm missing but with your explanation, I finally understand it. Thank you.